# Creating contra values in the same column SQL

Tags: sql-server

Aim to write a statement to produce a table with a numeric column that contains contra values, e.g.

```
Ref     Value
a       100
b       75
c       50
c       -50
b       -75
a       -100
```

I am new to SQL but aware it works row by row, so the only way I could think of doing this is write an initial SELECT statement into a temporary table and INSERT into my temporary table with the contra values, i.e.

```
SELECT  
  [Ref],  
  [Value]  
  INTO #Temp  
FROM  
  mytable
INSERT INTO #Temp ([Ref], [Value])
SELECT
  [Ref],
  0 - [Value]
FROM
  mytable
```

While this 'does the job' I fear it is 'messy' (could possibly cause problems when used for its intended purpose) and wondered if anyone would be able to provide a better solution.

Comment: Thanks in advance, apologies if duplicate or for my poor understanding of SQL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Union ALL` to combine the original and negative values. Then insert into temp table. Try this.

```
SELECT [Ref],
       [Value]
INTO   #Temp
FROM   (SELECT [Ref],
               [Value]
        FROM   mytable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [Ref],
               [Value] * -1
        FROM   mytable) a
```

If you just want to view the result remove the `into #temp` table

```
SELECT [Ref],
       [Value]
FROM   (SELECT [Ref],
               [Value]
        FROM   mytable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [Ref],
               [Value] * -1
        FROM   mytable) a
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, would this eliminate the need for a temporary table? (I'd like to get rid of it if poss, I'm assuming I'd just need to remove the 'INTO #Temp'?)